# Simulate phone locking on browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, mobile, simulator

I am currently developing an Asp .Net MVC application, and while I can use device toolbar (chrome) or Mozzila dev tools to test responsiveness, I have need to simulate device locking (when user locks his phone - mainly on some android tablets).

Is there a way to do this without using actual device? Some simulator maybe?

Comment: from a webapp view, going to a different app should be the same as locking. i think bluestacks can run any android browser (even if they push games hard nowadays)

Comment: Somewhat as I typed this question, I had put my app to "do stuff" ,and while I was in other tab, it actually did nothing. So I guess there goes my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @dandavis Hej man, I know it's been long since this question has been asked, but I just saw I have no answer on this question, and you helped me figure it out, so it would be nice of me to at thank you in form of SO points as well. Can you put your comment into answer so I can accept it?